# Error in Python multiprocessing process

Tags: python, centos, python-multiprocessing

I am trying a write a python code having multiple processes whose structure and flow is something like this:

```
import multiprocessing
import ctypes
import time
import errno
m=multiprocessing.Manager()
mylist=m.list()
var1=m.Value('i',0)
var2=m.Value('i',1)
var3=m.Value('i',2)
var4=m.Value(ctypes.c_char_p,"a")
var5=m.Value(ctypes.c_char_p,"b")
var6=3
var7=4
var8=5
var9=6
var10=7
def func(var1,var2,var4,var5,mylist):
    i=0
    try:
        if var1.value==0:
            print var2.value,var4.value,var5.value
            mylist.append(time.time())
        elif var1.value==1:
            i=i+2
            print var2.value+2,var4.value,var5.value
            mylist.append(time.time())
    except IOError as e:
        if e.errno==errno.EPIPE:
            var3.value=var3.value+1
            print "Error"
def work():
    for i in range(var3.value):
        print i,var6,var7,va8,var9,var10
        p=multiprocessing.Process(target=func,args=(var1,var2,var4,var5,mylist))
        p.start()
work()
```

When I run this code, sometimes it works perfectly, sometimes it does not run for exact amount of loop counts and sometimes I get following error:

```
0
1
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "dummy.py", line 19, in func
    if var1.value==0:
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 1005, in get
    return self._callmethod('get')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 722, in _callmethod
    self._connect()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 709, in _connect
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 149, in Client
    answer_challenge(c, authkey)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 383, in answer_challenge
    message = connection.recv_bytes(256)         # reject large message
EOFError
```

What does this error mean? What wrong am I doing here? What this error indicates? Kindly guide me to the correct path. I am using CentOS 6.5

Comment: Try removing the try except block to see if you get a different error message - use an if else block if possible

Comment: in your `elif` loop, you didn't define `i` so that will crash, but it's not the main issue IMO. Can you describe what you are trying to do?

Comment: @kezzos: I removed that try except block as well.... it didnt help

Comment: @HarryPotfleur: Sorry I forgot to declare that i. I am trying to develop a traffic generator tool... But that script was a bit complicated.. SO i simpliefied it a bit before raising this issue here

Answer (score -1):

Working with shared variables in multiprocessing is tricky. Because of the python Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), multiprocessing is not directly possible in Python. When you use the `multiprocessing` module, you can launch several task on different process, BUT you can't share the memory.
In you case, you need this so you try to use shared memory. But what happens here is that you have several processes trying to read the same memory at the same time. To avoid memory corruption, a process lock the memory address it is currently reading, forbidding other processes to access it until it finishes reading.
Here you have 3 processes trying to evaluate `var1.value` in the first `if` loop of your `func` : the first process read the value, and the other are blocked, raising an error.
To avoid this mechanism, you should always manage the `Lock` of your shared variables yourself.
You can try with syntax:

```
var1=multiprocessing.Value('i',0) # create shared variable
var1.acquire() # get the lock : it will wait until lock is available
var1.value # read the value
var1.release() # release the lock
```

External documentation :

Locks : https://docs.python.org/2/librar/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes
GIL : https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock

Comment: The processes are not trying to "read the same memory". Only one process is reading the memory which is the Manager. The other processes simply communicate with the Manager to get the data and there's no need for locking at all when reading unless it's critical that each process gets the last edited value (which means the lock needs to be held when writing as well).

Comment: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing
Here is a great explanation of why you should use lock with shared variables, even for reading

Comment: In the article, the use case is different. The processes are reading the value, incrementing it and writing it back. Since Atomicity is required it's necessary to synchronize access to the variable. However, in the OP's case synchronization or lack thereof is not the cause of his problem.

Comment: @HarryPotfleur: This is not working for me as my application requires to use manager and manager.value. Thanx for helping. Is there any other way to sort out this issue?

Comment: Anyhow I tried making use of mutex here like.. `    var1._mutex.acquire` and `    var1._mutex.release`   but that didn't work for me again